# Something similar to Objective-C categories in other languages?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented, objective-c

I understand Objective-C categories and how they become useful, but I always have a hard time explaining the concept to other programmers that are not familiar with Objective C.

Maybe I'm just bad at explaining things, but I was thinking at another way to explain it by comparing to similar features offered by other (more popular) languages. (ex : I can explain the similarities between Objective C protocols and Java Interfaces)

Any examples similar to Categories ?

Comment: Side note: Objective-C (and not C++ as is often falsely reported) was the main influence on Java. So, the similarities between Objective-C protocols and Java interfaces are easy to explain: they are the same thing!

Comment: Categories are not a difficult concept: *A category adds methods to a class.*

Comment: @JörgWMittag [that's true](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C#'s class extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) are basically the same thing done safely: you can only define methods that don't already exist, you can't violate encapsulation, and you can't compile code that imports the same extension method twice from different static classes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience with Objective C.

However, from what I've read, the **[Scala: Traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126)** or **[Mixin Class Composition](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/117)** seems to be **closest** to **categories**. Alternatively its a special case of **multiple inheritance** perhaps (C++).

I **dont think Java** has anything quite like it.

Comment: Categories are *not* a special case of multiple inheritance. When you create a category on a class, you're changing the class itself, not creating a subclass. Likewise, categories are not class composition. It's true that categories can be used to add an implementation of some interface to an existing class, and MI and composition can also be used to implement interfaces, but that's as far as it goes.